# Double quote issue in Object in Angular Component File

Tags: angular, typescript, froala

I have a component in this case its froala editor which allows you to create custom drop downs. to do so it takes an object in the format of

```
// Options for the dropdown.
  options: {
    'opt1': 'Option 1',
    'opt2': 'Option 2'
  },
```

i am using this dropdown to insert a place holders in the editor for mail merge. And my values are like this.

```
{
'{{ first_name | fallback: "" }}': 'First Name',
'{{ last_name | fallback: "" }}': 'Last Name'
}
```

when doing so instead of returning **{{ first_name | fallback: "" }}** it returns only **{{ first_name | fallback:** i tried to escape the " with a \ but that did not do anything. What do i need to do to have the full string returned ?

Comment: string interpolation is something to be used in the html...the options should be given in the .ts file.

Comment: the options are given in the component.ts file and not in templete html file

Comment: Hmm, why are you using interpolation in the .ts?

Comment: Because i tried anything i can come up with. I i use  "{{ first_name | fallback: '' }}": "First Name" it returns {{ first_name | fallback: '' }}

Comment: why not give the strings you need instead of wrapping them with `{{}}`.

Comment: because i use the {{ field name | fallback: String }} syntax on backend to do mail merge and replace the fields with the data from db and if there is no data or a null value i use the fall back string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203818/discussion-between-ramesh-and-misterniceguy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
"{{ last_name | fallback:   &#34&#34 }}"
```

and here is the link of characters
https://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

here is the stackblitz example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-froala-v3-custombutton-dynamic-sgzfvm